# Can anyone explain how std::string::npos works?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Cannot understand how the following code works.

```
String::npos
```

I cannot figure out how does it works. Please anyone help me out with that.

Comment: That code doesn't compile. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Clearly there must be more to this code than just what you have shown. Some earlier code must be calling a `find...()` method on a `std::string` and saving the result to the `found` variable, which will be set to `npos` if the searched-for data is not found in the string.

Comment: *"Is there any return value"* -- since there is no `return` statement, I'll go with "no". I suppose technically, there are values returned by the  `<<` operators (one value enabling the operator chain and the other unused) but that is probably not what you meant to ask about.

Answer (score -2):

**std::string::npos** returns an integer value **(-1)** which is used to determine whether or not a value is inside a string.

In the example provided here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos
you see the author uses **.find('a')** to find '**a**' char inside the string "test". Because the char 'a' does not hold a position in the string (npos literally translates to **no position**) it returns **-1**.

Comment: It doesn't "return" anything, it's a constant. Furthermore it must be unsigned (and therefore cannot have the value `-1`).